# Autoshare newly added content on my website to facebook group using my facebook account

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, share

I own a facebook group and I also own an announcements website.

When an user adds a new announcement on my website, I would like the website to autoshare the announcement on my facebook group using my facebook account. The user adding the announcement on my website is not required to have a facebook account, it won't be used anyway if he has one.

If the above scenario is possible, please let me know how can I implement it.

I am not sure this is relevant, but my website is using ASP.NET with C#.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This article is about image sharing, but im sure you can take some parts from it. http://blog.impact-works.com/2011/07/12/posting-to-facebook-wall-in-asp-netc-using-graph-apipart-5/